# rails: not finding stylesheets and images

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the code I have:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->    
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print' %>
    <!--[if lt IE 8]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie' %><![endif]-->
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom', :media => 'screen' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        <%= image_tag("logo.png", :alt => "Sample App", :class => "round") %>
        <nav class="round">
          <ul>
            <li><%= link_to "Home", '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Help", '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <section class="round">
        <%= yield %>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I put the stylesheets under public/stylesheets and the image under public/images. However the page is not being rendered with the css and images.

What am I missing?

Comment: Woah, they're up to 3.2 now? Hmm. Looks pretty seamless upgrade from 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place the stylesheets in `app/assets/stylesheets/`and images in `app/assets/images/` it should work! See the  Section 3.1.3 & 3.1.4 in Rails [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) about linking stylesheets & images